# JavaScript if function in console

Tags: javascript, if-statement, console

Hi I am very basic with JavaScript yet but I guess I have an understanding issue here...

I want to have at the end an output that gives the numer/age that is input and the text that is defined for each age specifically.

In the console I get it in 2 lines unfortunately and I really don't know how to change it:

```
Example: (input = 15)
you cannot do anything 
You are null years old and undefined!
```

```
console.clear();

let input = prompt("Enter your age!");
let result = whatCanIDo(input);


function whatCanIDo(input) {

  if (input <= 15) {console.log("you cannot do anything")}
  if (input >= 16) {console.log("you already can do things")}
  if (input >= 18) {console.log("you can do everything")}
  
}
  
console.log("You are " + input + " years old and " + result + "!");
```

Comment: Because your checks need to use else if and your checks overlap. You enter 20. It is greater than 16 so that is true. It is also greater than 18 so that is true. The code does not look at all the ifs and see what makes more sense, so you need to code it to understand that 18 is more importmant that 16 in this case.

Comment: Your function does not `return` anything. That's why `result` is `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you also very much for your quick reply, you guys are just GREAT :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See it's work!

```js
let input = prompt("Enter your age!");
let result = whatCanIDo(input);


function whatCanIDo(input) {

  if (input <= 15 ) {return "you cannot do anything" }
  if (input >= 16 && input <= 17 ) {return "you already can do things"} /* <-- Edited */
  if (input >= 18 ) {return "you can do everything" }
  
}

console.log("You are " + input + " years old and " + result + "!");
```

Comment: Ah ok the && is also a very good addition to it, thank you again very much :)

Comment: So I thought now I want to display it on the screen with a "Hello:" and then the result of the function. I tried this but get an error because of the innerHTMl where I want to add:

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the string value from the function **whatCanIDo** instead of (console.log) it, so that it is printed as undefined (nothing returned)
and for the prompt, it works fine, make sure you enter something there and click ok!

Here is a working example with hard coded input (years)

```js
console.clear();

let input = 15; //replace it with your code; prompt("Enter your age!");
let result = whatCanIDo(input);


function whatCanIDo(input) {

  if (input <= 15) {return "you cannot do anything" }
  if (input >= 16) {return "you already can do things"}
  if (input >= 18) {return "you can do everything" }
  
}

console.log("You are " + input + " years old and " + result + "!");
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed, thank you soooo much this was the mistake I made :). Thank you a 1000 times :)

Answer (score 0):

So I thought now I want to display it on the screen with a "Hello:" and then the result of the function. I tried this but get an error because of the innerHTMl where I want to add:

```
    console.clear();
    
    let input = prompt("Enter your age!");
    let result = whatCanIDo(input);
    let outputScreen = document.getElementById('outputField'); 
    let outputScreenResult = outputScreen.innerHTML += ("You are " + input + " years old" + result + "!");
    
    function whatCanIDo(input) {
    
      if (input < 16) {return (" and you cannot do anything")}
      if (input >= 16 && input <= 18) {return (" and you already can do things")}
      if (input = 18 && input <= 21) {return (" and you can do everything")}
      else {return(", so you are older then 18 so why you ask? :)")}
    }
  
        </script>
```

Hello:

Comment: <div id="outputField">
Hello: 
</div>

Comment: sorry found the solution, the div had to be on top of the script.... Sorry for bothering :)